# Install Mac OS on used Macbook Pro. Original owner and Apple ID unknown

Tags: macos

I bought a used macbook pro which had no hard disc. I do not know the original owners name or Apple ID. How do I install Mac OS?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the specific Mac model, but pretty much everything made since about 2011 can be recovered to the OS version that it first shipped with by holding  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  at the chimes.

You need to be connected to the Internet, preferably over ethernet & definitely not behind any type of Portal WiFi.

You will need to make sure the new drive you installed is formatted GUID/HFS+ not MBR [which is how they usually ship]. You should be able to do that from the Internet Recovery.